# AES GCM Python implementation

Tags: python, aes

I've recently started looking into encryption in python and I came across with pycryptodome library. I made this simple program that encrypt/decrypt a file using AES-GCM. Could someone take a look if I implemented the encryption and authentication correctly? For sake of simplicity, I'm posting only the encryption and makeKey functions.

```
import os
import struct
import secrets
import hahslib
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES


def makeKey(password, salt):    
    key = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512',password.encode('ascii'), salt, 1000000)
    return key[:32]

def encrypt(password, inputFileName):
    #creates the needed variables for encryption
    salt = secrets.token_bytes(16)
    key = makeKey(password, salt)
    nonce = secrets.token_bytes(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=nonce)
    #put the file size, salt and nonce in outputfile
    fileSize = os.path.getsize(inputFileName)
    with open("output", "wb") as outputFile:
        outputFile.write(struct.pack('<Q', fileSize))
        outputFile.write(salt)
        outputFile.write(nonce)
        #beginning of encryption itself
        chunkSize = 64 * 1024
        with open(inputFileName, "rb") as inputFile:
            while True:
                chunk = inputFile.read(chunkSize)
                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    outputFile.write(cipher.digest())
                    break
                outputFile.write(cipher.encrypt(chunk))
```

Answer (score 2):

### Handling files - the Python way

Without being able to test run your code at the momemt, there is one thing I can already recommend to you, which is to make use of Python's powerful [`with` statement](https://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm). Using `with` will make sure that files will be closed no matter what happens (e.g. unexpected exceptions). `with` also works with more than one file as described in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4617069/5682996).

Also consider adding the output filename as parameter to your function. You can even give your momentary value of `"output"` as default value.

---

### Minor notes on style

I'm not sure if you're aware of the official [Style Guide for Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), often just called PEP8. The official recommendation is to use `snake_case` for variable and function names. This would create a more unified code appearance when working with other Python libraries which often stick to that convention. As always, [exceptions](https://www.qt.io/qt-for-python) apply.

---

Below is your code including these changes.

```py
def make_key(password, salt):
    ...

def encrypt(password, input_filename, output_filename="output"):
    #creates the needed variables for encryption
    salt = secrets.token_bytes(16)
    key = make_key(password, salt)
    nonce = secrets.token_bytes(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=nonce)
    # put the file size, salt and nonce in outputfile
    filesize = os.path.getsize(input_filename)
    with open(output_filename, "wb") as output_file,\
         open(input_filename, "rb") as input_file:
        output_file.write(struct.pack('<Q', filesize))
        output_file.write(salt)
        output_file.write(nonce)
        #beginning of encryption itself
        chunkSize = 64 * 1024
        while True:
            chunk = input_file.read(chunkSize)
            if len(chunk) == 0:
                output_file.write(cipher.digest())
                break
            output_file.write(cipher.encrypt(chunk))
        print("File encrypted successfully!")
```